OpenAPI / Swagger: $ref for response statuses?
First of all, is this allowed by the OpenAPI spec? I could not find a clear answer, but it seems yes.
      401:
        $ref: 'Responses.yml#/401'
      404:
        $ref: 'Responses.yml#/404'

However, by using the official generator I get this error:
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -l openapi-yaml -i ./resources/api/v1.yml -o ./eqswagger -DoutputFile=openapi.yaml


java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load RELATIVE ref: Responses.yml path: ./resources/api

The file exists.
Is it possible that the structure of the Responses.yml is wrong? We have the status, each of them, on the top level and not below one element like "components".
204:
  description: No Content
  content: {}

401:
  description: Unauthorized
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        properties:
          $ref: "#/errors/properties"
        example:
          message: "Unauthorized request."
          code: 401

The whole trace:
5:18:52.687 [Thread-0] WARN  i.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser - Exception while resolving:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load RELATIVE ref: ./Responses.yml path: /resources/api
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.util.RefUtils.readExternalRef(RefUtils.java:220)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.ResolverCache.loadRef(ResolverCache.java:150)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.processors.ExternalRefProcessor.processRefToExternalResponse(ExternalRefProcessor.java:377)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.processors.ResponseProcessor.processReferenceResponse(ResponseProcessor.java:88)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.processors.ResponseProcessor.processResponse(ResponseProcessor.java:45)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.processors.OperationProcessor.processOperation(OperationProcessor.java:76)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.processors.PathsProcessor.processPaths(PathsProcessor.java:88)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIResolver.resolve(OpenAPIResolver.java:72)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIResolver.resolve(OpenAPIResolver.java:59)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.resolve(OpenAPIV3Parser.java:238)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readContents(OpenAPIV3Parser.java:181)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readLocation(OpenAPIV3Parser.java:97)
        at io.swagger.parser.OpenAPIParser.readLocation(OpenAPIParser.java:16)
        at io.swagger.codegen.v3.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput(CodegenConfigurator.java:615)
        at io.swagger.codegen.v3.cli.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:386)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find ./Responses.yml on the classpath
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.util.ClasspathHelper.loadFileFromClasspath(ClasspathHelper.java:33)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.util.RefUtils.readExternalRef(RefUtils.java:214)
        ... 15 common frames omitted


It's supposed to work. Is Responses.yml in the same folder as v1.yml? If you change the $refs to $ref: './Responses.yml#/404' (note the ./ at the beginning of the path), does it work? What version of Swagger Codegen do you use? (The latest version of its OAS3 codegen is 3.0.57). Also try https://openapi-generator.tech/ instead of Swagger Codegen.

It doesn't work with ./ either. I'm using version 3.0.57.

Yes, it looks correct except you have one thing which may be causing an issue
your properties definition is using a $ref for errors. I think your intention is to reference another schema for errors, but the way you've written it means the property itself will be called $ref. Some JSON parsers may try to evaluate this reference rather than identify it as a property key.
204:
  description: No Content
  content: {}

401:
  description: Unauthorized
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        properties:
          $ref: "#/errors/properties"  #  this is an actual property named `$ref`, not a reference
        example:
          message: "Unauthorized request."
          code: 401

fixed
204:
  description: No Content
  content: {}

401:
  description: Unauthorized
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        $ref: "#/errors/properties"
      example:
        message: "Unauthorized request."
        code: 401


Does your Responses.yml have a top level properties keyword or some other higher level node that you didn't show?
# responses.yml

properties:
  '200': ...
  '400': ...
  '401': ...

If it does, you need to drill down into the schema for the reference.
Responses.yml#/properties/401

Thank you, but I'm still getting the same error. :( My responses.yml does not have a top level property.

You may try quoting your response codes in Responses.yml like '401' instead of 401, to force them to be parsed as string. Some tools are picky about it.
